# Why did Door open a door to Richard?

Tags: character-motivation, neverwhere

Near the start of *Neverwhere* Croup and Vandemar have cornered Door. She uses her powers to open a door in a wall using the last of her energy. The relevant quote is

> 'If it's the last door I open' she prayed, silently to the Temple, to the Arch. 'Somewhere... anywhere...safe...' and then she thought wildly 'somebody'.

I understand why the door would take her to London Above as it is further from Croup and Vandemar although by that logic it should take her to China or something like that. The fact that she appeared next to Richard suggests the door was aiming for him. If this is the case why did the door take her to Richard and not someone who could help her like Marquis de Carabas or Old Bailey?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of universe: the story as Gaiman wanted to write it needed someone from London Above as the main protagonist to provide a familiar viewpoint. So that's what happened.

In universe: Richard was the first person ever to pass the Black Friars' third Ordeal, which needed to happen for Door to confront and defeat Islington and be finally, truly safe. Taking her to the Marquis or any other of her friends could have saved Door from Croup and Vandemar *for now*, but probably not from Islington.